# SD Card not working after reboot untill booted with another pi

Tags: boot, sd-card, raspbian-buster

Short: Pi sometimes wont boot until SD-Card runs in another pi first.

After a reboot attempt Pi #1 would not boot anymore. Only Red-LED glowing constantly, the green one did not even come on once. After some troubleshooting (Checking the SD-Card, running the Pi without anything connected, running it with monitor input) the pi still would not boot. Then i decided to put the SD-Card of Pi #1 into Pi #2. And it just boots and works. After putting the SD-Card back into Pi #1 it boots like nothing ever happened.

This happened already twice in a timespan of around 3 weeks.

Both Pi's are Raspberry Pi 4B running Raspberry PI OS Buster. The SD-Card is 32GB.

What could be the reason to this or how can i prevent this from happening?

Comment: Personally I would just ditch the SD Card. The Pi4 had some problems with some 32GB cards, There are proposed fixes, but don't think these have been rolled out.

Comment: Yeah i had some problems setting the card up. (Had to install raspberry pi os 3 times untill it booted but then it just worked for a few months) and is probably what im going to do. Thanks